# Creating a column based on the date range in R

Tags: r, date

I need to create a column based on the date range in another column 
Example :
I need to create a column "split" based on the column "Date" as shown in the data below .
First 5 days would be 1 and next 5 days would be 2 and so on .

I cant use the if else condition to create the new column as the date range is huge covering almost 10 years

```
    Date    ID  split
1/1/2017    ABC 1
1/2/2017    ABC 1
1/3/2017    ABC 1
1/4/2017    ABC 1
1/5/2017    ABC 1
1/6/2017    ABC 2
1/7/2017    ABC 2
1/8/2017    ABC 2
1/9/2017    ABC 2
1/10/2017   ABC 2
1/1/2017    xyz 1
1/2/2017    xyz 1
1/3/2017    xyz 1
1/4/2017    xyz 1
1/5/2017    xyz 1
1/11/2017   EFG 3
1/12/2017   EFG 3
1/13/2017   EFG 3
1/14/2017   EFG 3
1/15/2017   EFG 3
```

Comment: What happens as we cross from January into February?  Does the row number keep increasing, or does it reset?

Comment: If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the unnecessary transcription effort? **Please don't use images of data**, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar. ps: This site creates fixed ascii tables https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Data given a pictures can be informative, but seldom leads to rapid answers because people assume you expect them to do your data entry for them. Most of us see that as _your_ responsibility. We do not see it as a [MCVE]. The other severe deficiency of your question is the lack of any effort at coding. And finally, this sort of question should have been answered before, but if you searched, it would have been more convincing to see links to prior questions that failed to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify our understanding of what is wanted, we assume that the `ID` column is not involved in the calculation and we simply wish to assign 1 to the lowest 5 unique dates, 2 to the next lowest 5 unique dates and so on.  In the question every dates between the minimum and maximum appears at least once and so we assume that that is the case.  In terms of the data shown we want to assign 1 to the first 5 calendar days of January 2017, 2 to the next 5 calendar days of January 2017 and 3 for the next 5 calendar days of January 2017.

We can compute `split` as the number of days since the first day, divide that by 5 taking the integer part and adding 1.

No packages are used.

```
d <- as.Date(DF$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
transform(DF, split = as.numeric(d - min(d)) %/% 5 + 1)
```

giving:

```
        Date  ID split
1   1/1/2017 ABC     1
2   1/2/2017 ABC     1
3   1/3/2017 ABC     1
4   1/4/2017 ABC     1
5   1/5/2017 ABC     1
6   1/6/2017 ABC     2
7   1/7/2017 ABC     2
8   1/8/2017 ABC     2
9   1/9/2017 ABC     2
10 1/10/2017 ABC     2
11  1/1/2017 xyz     1
12  1/2/2017 xyz     1
13  1/3/2017 xyz     1
14  1/4/2017 xyz     1
15  1/5/2017 xyz     1
16 1/11/2017 EFG     3
17 1/12/2017 EFG     3
18 1/13/2017 EFG     3
19 1/14/2017 EFG     3
20 1/15/2017 EFG     3
```

### Note

We assume the following data in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "Date    ID
1/1/2017    ABC
1/2/2017    ABC
1/3/2017    ABC
1/4/2017    ABC
1/5/2017    ABC
1/6/2017    ABC
1/7/2017    ABC
1/8/2017    ABC
1/9/2017    ABC
1/10/2017   ABC
1/1/2017    xyz
1/2/2017    xyz
1/3/2017    xyz
1/4/2017    xyz
1/5/2017    xyz
1/11/2017   EFG
1/12/2017   EFG
1/13/2017   EFG
1/14/2017   EFG
1/15/2017   EFG"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```